# Lag Function for Dates

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to lag on date to get a value from 7 days ago. However, there is not a value for everyday in the dataset, but I want the value from 7 days ago rather then the value 7 before the current.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Currently doing LAG(field, 7) OVER (partition by x,y,z ORDER By date asc)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use range within window function definition instead of rows(default).
To make it possible, you can convert the column to Unix seconds by applying `UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(date))` conversion.

In the following code 604800 is equal to 7 days in seconds. You can change that value to use another range.

```
FIRST_VALUE(field) OVER (partition by x,y,z ORDER By UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(date)) asc RANGE BETWEEN 604800 PRECEDING AND 604800 PRECEDING)
```

Example query:

```
WITH rawdata AS
 (
  SELECT 'cat1' as name, DATE '2019-01-01' as date, 1 as val UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'cat1', DATE '2019-01-08', 3 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'cat1', DATE '2019-01-15', 7 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'cat2', DATE '2019-10-18', 10
)
SELECT 
  name,
  date,
  val,
  FIRST_VALUE(val)
    OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(date)) ASC
    RANGE BETWEEN 604800 PRECEDING AND 604800 PRECEDING) AS last_week_val
FROM rawdata
```